# Migration does not create column in database

Tags: django, django-models

`makemigrations` and `migrate` are working fine with no error. but when i check database it does not created

heres the model:

```
class Services(models.Model):
    service_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,related_name='sub_service')
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    service_icon = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    service_image = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active_status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    type = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    service_description = models.TextField( null=True, blank=True)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
```

I have added duration field later and its not giving me any error while running api

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column service_list_services.duration does not exist
LINE 1: ...", "service_list_services"."service_description", "service_l...
```

1. i have tried deleting migration files and then migrating but still..
   its not giving error while migrating but doesnot create row.
2. tried this `python manage.py migrate --fake`   still same

Comment: Have you tried looking at the django_migrations table in the DB? If you deleted a migration file manually, it could be that your DB is now out of sync

Comment: Have you saved your file when add new field too ?

Comment: @Dos you are correct. What could be done now to fix?

Comment: Do you have production data or you can clear migrations (e.g. you are working with local data)?

Comment: @Dos yes, I had to drop all tables atlast and then migrated again

Comment: I added a brief answer so I could add links and more info. Let me know if it is clear enough or you need more details :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing on your situation (Deleting + recreating all migrations may cause other issues such as circular dependencies depending on how models are constructed), I see two scenarios:

1. Development scenario (you can drop the db tables)

Restart with a clean persistence: drop the DB tables, delete migration files, run again `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands and commit the new migrations file

2. Production scenario (you cannot lose data)

Restore the deleted migration file, fix inconsistencies in the DB or in the file manually if you changed something by error, when you have code and db in sync do the changes again and make sure su use migrations every time you need to change the persistence.
, using the `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands.

If the code and the DB are in sync, you can use the [squashmigrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#squashmigrations) command

In general:
Avoid to delete a previous migration file, as it may cause dependency issues with other migrations. From [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing):

> You are encouraged to make migrations freely and not worry about how
> many you have; the migration code is optimized to deal with hundreds
> at a time without much slowdown. However, eventually you will want to
> move back from having several hundred migrations to just a few, and
> that’s where squashing comes in.